# Do I need DNSSEC from GoDaddy?

Tags: webserver, dnssec, domain

I just registered a co.uk domain with GoDaddy. I've been managing domains for a few years now, and hosting my own website. I know a bit, but not enough to be safe with anything important like this.

This is the first domain I've paid for - before I've used freenom.com.

While setting up my custom nameservers (I use CloudFlare for DNS and Crypto) they told me that they offer Premium DNS:

[image]

> ## DNSSEC
>
> Create an unbreakable chain that stops hackers from hijacking your website and stealing your data.
>
> ## Secondary DNS
>
> Protect your website's uptime and availability from power outages and internet routing problems.

This costs £2.39 per month. I don't want hackers to hijack my website or steal my data, but this does sound like scare tactics here.

I'm adding my domains DNS records to CloudFlare, and I noticed that they also offer DNSSEC. Do I need this at both steps?

Comment: If your whole domain is managed by Cloudflare your don't need to have DNSSec by GoDaddy too, but you have to protect the link from GoDaddy to Cloudflare (NS records). It does not look like that you need Premium for this but see [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/213586148-How-to-add-a-DS-record-to-GoDaddy) for details.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks, that was useful. What is GoDaddy trying to offer me? Is that the same as CloudFlare's DNSSec, but for if I used their DNS systems?

Comment: Exactly, this is useful if you manage your DNS with GoDaddy.

Comment: It's very unlikely that your clients support dnssec (most Operating Systems don't have it enabled by default), so this is probably useless to you.